# Map pointer going down in some mobiles

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Develop an app related to google maps on startup present location marker going down out of the screen in some mobiles like Sony Xperia.

I already implemented moveCamera and animateCamera to keep marker in center.

```
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);
```

If someone face same issue like this, please help me out in resolving this.

Thanks

Comment: check here on how to center zoom a marker  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611544/center-a-map-marker-in-android

Comment: I already implement this code. This is working in many of the mobiles like Samsung, Moto series etc but not working in Sony. I don't know why?